# I want to update parent record from child records value in oracle

Tags: oracle

I am looking to update below table

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
------- ------- -------
    123
    231     123 Abc
    431     123 Abc
```

After update it Table should look like below

```
Column1 Column2 Column3
------- ------- -------
    123         Abc
    231     123 Abc
    431     123 Abc
```

I have to update more then 200 thousands records of a table in oracle. any help here would be much appreciated

Comment: Please edit your question to post data in tabular format, as formatted text; also, please add your needed result and what you tried so far

Comment: What if you have another row, say `555, 231, 'A'`?

Comment: To the upvoter, how does this question show effort? or is it useful and clear?

Comment: Or even `765, 123, DEF`? (a child of the same parent with a different `col3` value)

Comment: Your recent edit makes the question even harder to digest.  You might want to do something before you get closed out.

Comment: i am not sure what exactly @TimBiegeleisen is looking for ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen is explaining you that this question is not clear, as you can see from the comments and the numerous questions you did not answer. So your question will likely be closed in a few, if you don't edit it to make it clear. You might have a look at [mcve] and [ask] to improve your question.

Comment: i have updated it again to give a better idea.

Comment: You still have some questions to answer... To be honest, if you don't want to help us, why should us want to help you?

Comment: Sorry @Aleksej i always be helpful , but i am not sure how to help in this scenario.

Comment: I asked "What if you have another row, say 555, 231, 'A'?". @MT0 added "Or even 765, 123, DEF? (a child of the same parent with a different col3 value)"... let's start by these

Comment: for case one if there is another row, say 555, 231, 'A' --> result would be looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform the update using `MERGE`

```
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING
(
  SELECT   col2,
           MIN( col3 ) AS col3
  FROM     table_name
  GROUP BY col2
  HAVING   MIN( col3 ) = MAX( col3 )
) src
ON ( dst.col2 IS NULL AND dst.col1 = src.col2 )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET col3 = src.col3 WHERE col3 IS NULL;
```

The `HAVING` line is in there to prevent updates when children might have different values for the `col3` column.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET col3 = (SELECT DISTINCT t2.col3 FROM yourTable t2 WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col2)
WHERE col3 IS NULL
```

This solution assumes that children entries which appear in `col1` always share one common parent.  If not, then my query will fail, but then so will your current approach to update your table.

Comment: What happens when you have rows: `231,123,A` and `444,123,B`?

Comment: @MT0 This should not happen if I read the OP correctly, because all children should share a common parent.

Comment: Its too slow to work if numbers of records are huge , i have more then 286560 records to update

Comment: Oracle doesn't support update join syntax, so this might be your only option.

Comment: The OP's example happens to have the children have the same value for `col3` but I see nothing in the post to say that this condition is mandated.

Comment: @MT0 Then the problem is non tractable, because in that case knowing your children does not yield a single distinct value.  If you really believe this, you should vote to close the question.